Правильно ли оформлена фраза в кавычках?
Она хотела назвать это словами "попасть в безвыходную ситуацию", однако пока что-то мешало ей это сделать.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, верно ли оформлена фраза в кавычках? Должна ли она писаться с маленькой или с большой буквы, нужно ли перед ней ставить двоеточие?

назвать словами - плеоназм, -  хотела это назвать. однакопока - звучит, как кто-то попрощался:.. однако, ей пока что-то мешало это сделать.

извините, но вопрос был не об этом.

наверное, мне показалось это не менее важным)

Оформление корректное, другого варианта просто нет.

Слова "попасть в безвыходную ситуацию" – это все равно что словосочетание "попасть в безвыходную ситуацию". А в этом случае кавычки нужны обязательно; буква строчная, двоеточие не используется.

Это приложение "слова, словосочетание" перед содержанием этого словосочетания. Такова грамматика.


Сравнить: слово "ситуация", словосочетание "безвыходная ситуация".

Двоеточие нужно перед однородным рядом, например: слова "ситуация, попасть, безвыходный".


Она хотела это назвать: "Попасться переделку," - однако, что-то мешало ей это сделать, пока...
я бы так оформил, если это именно слова героини, она называет. Можно также добавить жаргона: попасться в переделочку, ситуёвину и тп. Была бы яркая запоминающаяся фраза.
А если это общие какие-то фразы, то как есть.
